# No difference in dataframe after for loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am new to Stackoverflow and haven't found a topic that could already answer my question so I am posting it here now!

I am trying to change yes/no-characters in a dataframe to integers 1 and 2. I want to do this for only four out of 45 subjects. I wanted to go for a for loop with an ifelse-statement to do this. The loop seems to work at first but there is no change in my dataframe when I open it or have a look with head(data).

The dataframe is called "gatingdata" and the column "correct_buttonBox".

This is what I did:

```
ffor row in 1:nrow(gatingdata$correct_buttonBox)) {
  if (gatingdata$subject_nr == "19") {
    ifelse(gatingdata$correct_buttonBox=="no", 1, 2)
  }  if (gatingdata$subject_nr == "27") {
    ifelse(gatingdata$correct_buttonBox=="no", 1, 2)
  } if (gatingdata$subject_nr == "35") {
    ifelse(gatingdata$correct_buttonBox=="no", 1, 2)
  } if (gatingdata$subject_nr == "42") {
    ifelse(gatingdata$correct_buttonBox=="no", 1, 2)
  }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
for(row in 1:nrow(gatingdata$correct_buttonBox)) {
  which[(gatingdata$subject_nr == "19"),] {
    ifelse(gatingdata$correct_buttonBox=="no", 1, 2)
  }  which[(gatingdata$subject_nr == "27"),] {
    ifelse(gatingdata$correct_buttonBox=="no", 1, 2)
  } which[(gatingdata$subject_nr == "35"),] {
    ifelse(gatingdata$correct_buttonBox=="no", 1, 2)
  } which[(gatingdata$subject_nr == "42"),] {
    ifelse(gatingdata$correct_buttonBox=="no", 1, 2)
  }
}
```

I also tried using " i in 1:length(data$column)". Didn't work either.

I would be very thankful if somebody could tell me what I'm doing wrong! I couldn't find any information related to my problem in an online search and I've been trying to solve this for several hours now. This is the 7th or 8th version of the loop but to me, this seems like the most logic....

Best,

M.H.

Comment: You didn't use `row` within your `for` loop at all....

Comment: Syntactically this is a bit of a mess, I'd take some time to learn how to construct for loops and if else statements. YOu're also using `which` wrong.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the output of `dput(head(gatingdata, 50))`? This would let us see the first 50 rows of your data set, which will make it much easier to help.

Comment: Thank all of you so much for your answers! 

I indeed solved it without a for loop now! I see that looping is a bit more complex than my supervisor expected it to be for me. I found s.b. at my university who is going to give more seminars for statistical methods and I'm going to attend that!

Answer (score 0):

A few problems:

1. Looping in this way is rarely the correct solution in R (logical indexing would be better).
2. You are not storing the results of the `ifelse` calls anywhere.
3. "correct_buttonBox" appears to be character data, yet you are attempting to swap in numeric data.

A more efficient way to do this, without loops, would be to take advantage of R's logical indexing. Something like the following might work. I would recommend you examine the result of each line of code here to understand what is happening. Note that I am always using character data here (i.e., `subject == '42'`, not `subject == 42`, but it's not clear from your example that this is correct. Use `str(gatingdata)` to examine your data's format.

```
subjects <- gatingdata$subject %in% c('19', '27', '35', '42') # logical vector of subjects of interest
yes <- gatingdata$correct_buttonBox == 'yes' # logical vector of 'yes' responses
no <- gatingdata$correct_buttonBox == 'no' # logical vector of 'no' responses

gatingdata$correct_buttonBox[subjects & yes] <- '2' # recode yes's
gatingdata$correct_buttonBox[subjects & no] <- '1' # recode no's
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick and helpful answer! The loop was a recommendation from a supervisor.... I will try your suggestion! It seems way more traceable and logic to me!

Comment: The only thing I do not understand is, how do I make the change happen inside my dataframe? Do I have to nest all of this inside an apply-function?

Comment: There are many ways to access and modify the contents of data frames. Try typing ?”$”

Comment: If I do it with the code you posted, there is nothing happening in my dataframe. It still looks like before. Maybe there is another problem.